# HSPI Package Installation Error

Tags: hspi

I can't get this working on my second laptop. As soon as I try and create a new project I get the attached error message in VS. Anyone have any ideas at all?

(OP at https://forums.homeseer.com/showpost.php?p=1295842&postcount=32)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I actually just fixed it. I swear as soon as I ask something, it gets fixed. I had to change this setting in VS to get it to work:

Tools -> Options-> Projects and Solutions-> General -> Setting: Save new projects when created (checked)

(OP at https://forums.homeseer.com/showpost.php?p=1295847&postcount=33)